# $a\cdot \cos x\cdot \sin y + b\cdot \sin x\cdot \sin y + c\cdot \cos x = 0$ what are the values of $a$, $b$, and $ c$

Tags: trigonometry

$a\cdot \cos x\cdot \sin y + b\cdot \sin x\cdot \sin y + c\cdot \cos x = 0$  what are the values of $a, b, c$

My steps:
I was solving  a little different equation as
$$a\cos x + b \sin x = 0$$
$$or, \frac{a}{\sin x} = - \frac{b}{ \cos x} $$
so $a = -\sin x$,  and $b = \cos x$

following the same way I was trying :
$a\cdot \cos x\cdot \sin y + b\cdot \sin x\cdot \sin y + c\cdot \cos x = 0 $  dividing by $\cos x \sin y \sin x$
$$\frac{a}{\sin x} + \frac{b}{ \cos x} + \frac{c}{\sin y \sin x} = 0$$
then what are the values of a, b and c respectively?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are loads of solutions. Even in the easier example, you gave only one of infinitely many solutions. $a = -8\sin x$, $b = 8\cos x$ works as well, to give an example.

Comment: Thank you. How should I solve for a, b and c?

Comment: You should look up how to solve a linear systems of equations. In this case: Choose $a$ and $b$ arbitrarily, solve for $c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is

> $a\cdot \cos x\cdot \sin y + b\cdot \sin x\cdot \sin y + c\cdot \cos x = 0$  what are the values of $a, b, c$

This linear equation in variables $\,a, b, c\,$ can be
interpreted using the 3D vectors

$$ \vec{v} = (a, b, c),\quad \vec{u} = (\cos x\cdot \sin y,
\,\sin x\cdot \sin y,\,\cos x). $$

The equation becomes $\, \vec{v}\cdot\vec{u} = 0.\,$ That is,
$\,\vec{v}\,$ and $\,\vec{u}\,$ are orthogonal.

If $\, \vec{u} = \vec{0}\,$ then any vector $\,\vec{v}\,$
satisfies  the equation. Now assume that $\,\vec{u}\,$ is
nonzero. Then the set of solutions $\,\vec{v}\,$ form a plane
which passes through the origin. Use the three basis vectors

$$ \vec{e_1}=(1,0,0),\quad
   \vec{e_2}=(0,1,0),\quad \vec{e_3}=(0,0,1) $$

to define the vectors

$$ \vec{v_1}=\vec{e_1}\times\vec{u},\quad
\vec{v_2}=\vec{e_2}\times\vec{u},\quad
\vec{v_3}=\vec{e_3}\times\vec{u}.$$

From a property of the cross product, these three vectors are
all orthogonal to $\,\vec{u}.\,$ If all three of them are the
zero vector then $\,\vec{u}=\vec{0}\,$ which is contrary to our
assumption. If two of them are zero, for example, $\,\vec{v_1}\,$
and $\,\vec{v_2},\,$ then this implies that $\,\cos x = \sin y = 0\,$
and then $\,\vec{u}=\vec{0}\,$ which is contrary to our assumption.
The remaining case is at least two of $\,v_1,v_2,v_3\,$ are nonzero.
Pick any two of them as a basis for the plane.

---

A more elementary approach is to consider consider two cases. The
first case is $\,\cos x=0.\,$ Substituting this in the original
equation leads to $\, b\cdot \sin x\cdot \sin y = 0\,$
and $\,a,c\,$ is arbitrary. Since, now $\,|\!\sin x|=1,\,$ this
leads to $\, b\cdot \sin y= 0\,$ where $\,b\,$ is arbitrary or
$\,b=0\,$ depending on if $\,\sin y=0\,$ or not.

The second case is  $\,\cos x\ne 0.\,$ This leads to

$$ -(a\cdot \cos x\cdot \sin y + b\cdot \sin x\cdot \sin y)/(\cos x)
 = c $$

where $\,a,b\,$ are arbitrary and $\,c\,$ is uniquely determined by
the previous equation.

Comment: Thank you so much! Still I have confusion to find the value of a, b and c from this information/equation.

Comment: @Mon Thanks for that comment! I have added a more elementary method.

Comment: Thank you very much again